# Is it possible to delete cart and its cart items using CommerceCart api?

Tags: apex, commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce

I've noticed that invoking `CommerceCart.deleteCart` method does not cascade the deletion on its Cart Items.
Am I doing something wrong, or is it a correct behavior?
The description of this method in the documentation is very brief and does not contain any information.

**Update**
I've investigated it more deeply, and it seems that after the `deleteCart` method is invoked the status of cart changes to `PendingDelete`, so the deletion job is queued. However I want that job to be fired right after I invoke the `deleteCart`.

Comment: Hello Rechu, may I ask what is the requirement for the job to be kicked out immediately? I'm asking because the cart under Pending Delete status are not visible anymore.

Comment: I have a Trigger on CartItem delete, that makes some important logic for me.

Comment: But I've already resolved my issue, by just running a DML delete on CartItems, and I left Cart to be deleted via CommerceCart api.